# Netbeand 7.1 and PHPUnit 3.6.10

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I have been trying to run simple PHPUnit tests with Netbeans 7.1 and PHPUnit 3.6.10 on Xampp 1.7.7

I have downloaded PHPUnit using PEAR and when I type the following, I get the output below

C:\xampp\php\PEAR>phpunit --version

PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Netbeans 7.1 is my problem.  I have configured the following

Tools -> Options ->PHP (PHP 5 Interpreter)  is  **C:\xampp\php\php.exe**

Tools -> Options ->PHP (Unit Testing) **C:\xampp\php\phpunit.bat**

I keep getting the dreaded

**Selected PHPUnit (version ?.?.?) is too old, upgrade it if possible (the minimum version in 3.3.0)**

displayed.

Has **ANYONE** solved this issue?

PS the irony is, it was working at one stage!

Stephan

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

I'm a WAMP guy, so I don't know XAMPP paths, but this is what you need to do:

Your PEAR path is wrongly set to C:\php5\pear. This is the development setting. Wamp/Xampp should have changed it, but they didn't.

The Solution:

1. Edit every php.ini file, change INCLUDE_PATH to your path where WAMP Server is installed(e.g. C:\WAMP\bin\php\php5\includes).
2. Now run go-pear.bat, and follow all the instructions. If everything is fine then its OK. You can check it by running http://localhost/phpinfo(). Else if go to Step 3.
3. Right Click My Computer->Advanced Tab->Environment Variables->Add New User Variable->PHP_PEAR_INCLUDE_PATH->Add new value->The path where PEAR is installed(e.g. C:\WAMP\bin\php\php5\PEAR).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Your suggestions don't work for me.  I have a copy of xampp on my external hard disk.  PHPUNIT Netbeans 7.1 works on my desktop computer with xampp on my external hard disk, but not on my laptop.  It appears it is a Netbeans issue.

Comment: Yes it does.  PHPUnit does work via the command line.  This makes me think it really is a NB issue.  It really has me puzzled.  On my laptop I removed all  JDKs and NB.  Reinstalled NB 7.1 and STILL get the Selected PHPUnit (version ?.?.?) is too old, upgrade it if possible (the minimum version in 3.3.0).  I just don't know

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed by adding `c:\xampp\php` into the `PATH` environment.

Guessing Netbeans, check phpUnit via the cmd:

```
C:\>phpunit --version

PHPUnit 3.6.11 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```